# MS Access database SQL query issue in windows 10

Tags: c++, sql, windows, ms-access, windows-10

I have been using MS access database ( *.MDB) in a 64-bit format in windows 7 (64-bit) for quite some time. The Access SQL is called from a C++ module.
I have recently upgraded my OS to windows 10, I am still able to open connection to the ODBC (user DSN in this case), however, it seems my earlier program can no longer open the table or run queries. I am unsure what are my options now, please advice.
Should I use .accdb in place of .mdb ?

Comment: Did you install Microsoft Jet?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. No. I install Microsoft Access 2010 64-bit ODBC driver

Comment: You need `Jet OLEDB` if you want to open the MDB file directly, but apparently it's dead, look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811179/where-how-can-i-download-and-install-the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-windows-8

Comment: @GuillaumeF. The MDB opens and its working alright on win7 still . Whats wrong on win10?

Comment: Perhaps you should try an accdb version of the file and see what happens. Be sure to keep the original mdb in case you have to go back to it.

Comment: accdb solved the issue on win10.Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing I found that changing from .mdb to 
.accdb did solve the problem. I am posting so that I can close this thread and perhaps benefit someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing provider in connection string : "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" Like this if not yet done so.